# Root discriminant lower bounds in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ramification

Let $X$ be a simply-connected smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$.  Let $C$ be a curve on $X$.

If $Y$ is a ramified cover of $X$ of degree $n$, and $D$ is the branch divisor of $Y$, call $(D \cdot C)/n \in \mathbb Q$ the root discriminant of $Y$. Intuitively, this measures the total amount of ramification of the cover $Y$.

Let $r_n$ be the minimal root discriminant among all $Y$ of degree $n$ over $X$.

> What is $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} r_n$?

I want to know how ramified a cover must be. Since low-degree covers can be very exceptional and might have unusually small ramification, I'm asking about covers of sufficiently large degree - thus, a $\lim \inf$.

We can get an upper bound by finding a movable divisor $D$ and a rationally equivalent divisor $D'$ and taking the cyclic cover that adjoins an $n$th root of a function whose zeroes are $D$ and poles are $D'$, whose branch divisor will be $(n-1)(D+D')$. This shows that $r_n \leq 2 (D \cdot C)$ whenever $D$ is movable.

For $X=C=\mathbb P^1$, we can prove that this is optimal, using Riemann-Hurwitz. $r_n=2-2/n$, so $\lim \inf_{n\to\infty} r_n=2$. This suggests the guess:

> Are there conditions on $X$ and $C$ that imply that $\lim \inf_{n\to \infty} r_n$ is equal to $2 \min_D (D \cdot C)$, where the minimum is taken over all movable divisors $D$ ?

Unfortunately, I can't verify any higher-dimensional case of this.

This question was motivated by an attempt to find an analogue of a difficult question in number theory. The analogy is that $X$ is like $\mathbb Q$, $Y$ is like a number field, the branch divisor $D$ is like the discriminant of that number field, the intersection number $D \cdot C$ is like the log of the discriminant, so dividing it by $n$ is like the log of the [root discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Root_discriminant). The number theory question is to find the minimal value of the root discriminant among fields of large degree. This is known to be between $22.3$ and $93$, and these bounds turn out to be useful for some [interesting applications](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274493).

Varieties of dimension $1$ are the most natural analogues of number fields, but this question is solved completely in dimension $1$, where there is just one simply-connected variety. Thus I generalized the question to higher dimensions, using an intersection number $D \cdot C$ to measure the size of the divisor $D$. Other measures of the size of $D$, such as the self-intersection number, might also be interesting.

Comment: Did you mean for $Y$ to be in some way related to $C$ as a cover of $X$?

Comment: @KConrad: No. $C$ is just there to turn $D$ into a number.

Answer (score 3):

When $X$ is a curve, the Riemann-hurwitz formula is the only condition on $D$.
Once $X$ has positive genus, $\deg D$ can be any even number,
including zero.  For example, if $X$ is an elliptic curve then
there are isogenies $X' \rightarrow X$ of arbitrary degree;
more generally $X$ embeds into its Jacobian, and the fiber product
of the embedding $X \hookrightarrow J(X)$ with any isogeny
$\phi: A \rightarrow J(X)$ gives an unramified cover of $X$
whose degree equals $\deg\phi$.  When $X$ has genus at least $2$
one can also construct non-abelian unramified covers from suitable
maps from $\pi_1(X)$ to finite non-abelian groups.

In particular, if $X$ has positive genus then $\liminf_n r_n = 0$.

(Perhaps the OP knows this already, but it doesn't seem to be stated
anywhere in the question statement or the comments thus far.)

Comment: I indeed knew this, which is why I assumed in the question that $X$ is simply connected. But it's probably good to state this explicitly. Indeed, this reminds me of a useful technique for upper bounding $\lim \inf r_n$: If $Y$ is cover of $X$ with root discriminant $r$ and has infinite etale fundamental group, then all etale covers of $Y$ are ramified covers of $X$ with root discriminant $r$, so $\lim \inf_n r_n \leq r$.

Comment: In fact, one can use this to show that $\lim \inf_n r_n$ is not necessarily nonnegative: Take $A$ an abelian surface, $X$ a Kummer surface created by blowing up $A/\{\pm 1\}$, $C$ one of the exceptional $-2$ curves from this blowup. Let $Y$ be the blowup of all the $2$-torsion points of $A$, then $Y$ is a double cover of $X$ ramified only at the $16$ exceptional curves, so $D \cdot C= C\cdot C=-2$, so $r=-1$, and $\lim\inf_n r_n \leq -1$!

Comment: Right, "simply connected" excludes curves of positive genus.

Comment: You can leverage Noam's examples into examples with $X$ simply connected yet $\liminf_n r_n$ equal to $0$.  For instance, let $X$ be the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at the $d^2$ basepoints of a general pencil of degree $d$ plane curves, and let $C$ be a fiber of the projection $\pi:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$.  For the generic fiber $X_\eta$, for every integer $m$, associated to the multiplication map $[m]:J(X_\eta)\to J(X_\eta)$, there is an associated branched cover $X_m \to X$ that is branched only over the singular fibers of $\pi$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks for the idea! Note that there is another branched cover that is ramified over the singular fibers - take some branched cover of $\mathbb P^1$ ramified over the singular points, and pull it back. So this seems very similar to the upper bound of $2(D \cdot C)$, for $D$ movable, in this case a fiber. In the $d=3$/elliptic surface case I computed that the pullback construction gives you better upper bounds. Do you think the multiplication-by-$m$ construction might do better for higher genus curves?